# Efficiently calculating autocorrelations and cross-correlations from high-dimensional time-series with Python?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, statistics

I have a coordinate array of shape `X.shape = (100000, 1000)` and a property array of shape `P.shape = (100000, 1000)`. I wish to calculate the distance dependent autocorrelation function of property `P` which I explain below.

First I remind that the "bare" autocorrelation of `P` would be `Autocorrelation = [np.mean(P[tau:]*P[:-tau], axis=(0, 1)) for tau in range(P.shape[0])]`.

For the distance dependent autocorrelation, I have to find all points whose `tau`  shifted coordinates are within a given distance `d`. That is, I look for all indices `i` and `j` along `axis=1` for which `np.abs(X[time, i]-X[time+tau, j]) == d` and I save the times along `axis=0` each time I find such pairs, then I build the averages for each `tau` and `d`.

For a given `tau` I wrote the function shown below

```
import numpy as np
from joblib import Parallel, delayed  

X = np.ones([100000, 1000])
P = np.ones([100000, 1000])

def Myfunc(tau):

   AutocorrelationP = []

    for t in range(X.shape[0]-tau):
    
        d = np.round(np.sqrt((X[time][:, None]-X[time+tau])**2))
    
        Pd = []
    
        for i in np.arange(1, 11):   
        
            Indices = np.where(d==i)
        
            Pd.append(np.mean(P[time, Indices[0]]*P[time+tau, Indices[1]]))
        
        AutocorrelationP.append(Pd)
    
    return np.mean(np.array(AutocorrelationP), axis=0)
```

I call Parallel from Joblib to run this function on 10 CPU cores for the different values of `tau`. At the moment the script seems to be fine and all CPUs are loaded to 100% in green in htop.

The problem is that the parallelization overhead gets large if I use all 64 CPUs on my node. I expected calling `myFunc` 64 times in parallel from Joblib would involve strictly no overhead as the tasks are independent (except that they read from the same variables). But it seems that this is only true if I run up to 10 jobs in parallel, and starting from 10 I can see roughly a linear increase of runtime as a function of the job number.

I did this "runtime vs job number" calculation for different sizes of `P` and `X` to understand the problem, and I saw that this behavior is only seen if `X.shape[1]` is large, while the overhead disappears if `X.shape[1]` is roughly 100. In the extreme case of `X.shape[1]=5000` all CPUs turn to red during execution. So from these tests I understand that memory is the main issue. `X.shape[0]` has also a less significant but still noticeable effect. Can you suggest the reason of this problem ?

**My solution**

To avoid the memory problem I try to avoid building distance matrices from numpy broadcasting and try to rely on explicit Python loops decorated with numba instead. Here is my implementation :

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def myFunc(tau):

    PAutocorrelation = np.zeros(11)

    for t in range(X.shape[0]-tau):  

        for i in range(X.shape[1]):

             for j in range(X.shape[1]):

                  PAutocorrelation[int(np.rint(np.abs(X[t, i]-X[t+tau,j])))] += P[t, i]*P[t+tau, j]  

    return PAutocorrelation
```

Actually this approach seems to be better with regard to parallelization overhead tested on smaller arrays. But if I use the array dimensions mentioned above, the kernel dies. So I think this numba approach also suffers from a memory problem although no additional large matrices are computed here. Can you suggest why ?

Finally, here is slightly improved faster alternative based on numpy but it suffers from the same problem as the first approach

```
from fast_histogram import histogram1d

def myFunc(tau):
    
    PAutocorrelation = []

    for t in range(100):

         PAutocorrelation.append( \
           histogram1d(np.abs(x[time][:, None]-X[time+tau]).flatten(), \
                       bins=10, range=[0., 10], \
                     weights=(P[time][:,None]*P[time+tau]).flatten())] )    

     return PAutocorrelation
```

Comment: Which OS do you use and which CPU? The effect you mention are likely dependent of the target platform. I see no Numba memory issue on my PC nor scalability issue so far (on only 6 cores).

Comment: Note that Numpy array should not be global one in Numba functions. Numba assume they are compile-time constant. It can also cause some weird effect. Please consider passing arrays as parameters. Global variables are seen as bad for both software engineering (cause a lot of maintainability issues) and performance (slower).

Comment: I used 64 CPUs. I would consider passing the arrays as parameters, but I usually avoid that because of the potential copying overhead.

Comment: There is no copy when you pass arrays in parameters of a function. In fact, it is true for all variable type in Python (variable are references and objects are reference counted). Regarding the CPU, I mean the exact reference (e.g. "Intel i5-9600KF"). 64 CPUs is almost meaningless (actually, it is cores, not CPUs).